# The parameter b from SVM in case of Gaussian kernel

Tags: machine-learning, svm, gaussian

I read about SVM and the case when we take as a kernel Gaussian kernel, and as I understood in the case of Gaussian kernel, it only cares about that if point is near to the some point, then the "color" of these points will be the same. And if I'll ask him to give me a "color" of a point which are far away from data points then he will answered me 0, which will means something like "I don't know". And I know that if I'll ask the predictor the color of that point, he will return b. The proof is below

[image]

Can we say that in case of Gaussian kernel b is equal to 0?

Answer (score 1):

No, if we see the final decision function of SVM with Gaussian kernel as given below:
[image: SVM Decision function]
and Gaussian function is as follows:
[image: Gaussian function]
we can see the 'sigma' parameter and 'signum' function here. The end result would be greater than zero for one class and vice versa.
So to find a plane (instead of a line for linear case) that separates these two classes, we need to adjust the values of b and sigma. These values vary from problem to problem. Hence, not necessarily be zero. 
Researchers have utilized different optimization algorithms to get optimum values, i.e. Particle Swarm Optimization, Grey Wolf Optimization etc.
For example, the value of 'sigma' inflicts overfitting problem, and small value results in the under-learning problem. So it should be optimized.
For more information, you can read following open access article as an example.
[The Impact of Different Kernel Functions on the
Performance of Scintillation Detection Based on
Support Vector Machines](https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/19/23/5219)
I have used both PSO and GWO optimization algorithms to optimize key parameters of Least square support vector machine given below in my open-access research article:
[Optimization of LSSVM parameters reference](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/342120520_A_Non-linear_Model_Predictive_Control_Based_on_Grey-Wolf_Optimization_Using_Least-Square_Support_Vector_Machine_for_Product_Concentration_Control_in_L-Lysine_Fermentation)